# Executing a stored procedure as a result of merge statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-merge

I am using a `MERGE` statement in a stored procedure that looks like this:

```
        MERGE Sections AS sTarget
        USING @Sections AS sSource
        ON sTarget.SectionID = sSource.SectionID
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            <INSERT STATEMENT>
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET
                IsActive = CASE WHEN sSource.IsDeleted = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
                                                                ^
                                                                A
```

Where `@Sections` is a parameter passed to the stored procedure.

Now I want to execute a stored procedure called `spDeleteSection` that accepts `SectionID` as a parameter and (soft) deletes all the divisions and subdivisions under the section and returns 0. I want to execute this procedure at 'A'.

Can this be done? If so how? If it cannot be done where am I supposed to execute this to get the same result?

Note :

- `@Sections` is a user defined table
- `SectionID` is obtained form `sSource.SectionID`

Comment: Capture the results using the output l
Clause and then pass then to your sp. Ideally also in a table valued parameter, but one at a time is also possible.

Comment: Note you reference `@section` and `@sections` - which is it?

Comment: I think you're asking two things: 1. HOw to dynamically define sSource (using a variable, `@Sections`); 2. How to do something with the result

Answer (score 0):

You can capture each merged row using an `OUTPUT` clause into a table variable.

Then simply join that table in a `DELETE`.

Do not be tempted to execute something row-by-row over this table variable, it's likely to be slow. Do a single joined delete.

```sql
DECLARE @output TABLE (SectionID int PRIMARY KEY, action nvarchar(10))

MERGE Sections AS sTarget
USING @Sections AS sSource
ON sTarget.SectionID = sSource.SectionID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    <INSERT STATEMENT>
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
      IsActive = CASE WHEN sSource.IsDeleted = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
OUTPUT sTarget.SectionID, $action
  INTO @output (SectionID, action);
;

DELETE d
FROM Division d
JOIN @output o ON o.SectionID = d.SectionID
WHERE o.action = 'UPDATE';
```

If necessary, you can dump the correct rows from this table variable into a Table Valued Parameter and execute a separate procedure with that.